# JQuery - Load table and insert it with html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

i want to load a html table in a div

The HTML-Code is loaded via:

```
$("#table_wrapper").hide();
$.get("<?echo base_url();?>schichtplan/employee_fields/"+plan_id+"true",function(data){
    $("#table_wrapper").html(data);
    $("#table_wrapper").show();
});
```

Data is validated via alert and looks like:

```
<table border= '0'cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0' class='mitarbeiter' /> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
<th>&nbsp</th><th><div id='plan_id:1;sort_id:1' class='edit_employee'>User1</div></th><th><div id='plan_id:1;sort_id:2' class='edit_employee'>User2</div></th></tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
<td class='first'>Anstellung</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr> 
<tr> 
<td class='first'>Stundenlohn</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr> 
<tr> 
<td class='first'>Festlohn</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr> 
<tr> 
<td class='first'>Bonus</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr> 
<tr> 
<td class='first'>Kassenminus</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr> 
<tr> 
<td class='first'>Nachtzuschlag</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr> 
<tr> 
<td class='first'>Sonstiges</td><td>&nbsp</td><td>&nbsp</td></tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>
```

After the JQuery-Action the div looks like:

```
<div id="table_wrapper" style="display: block; "><table border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" class="mitarbeiter"></table>

&nbsp;<div id="plan_id:1;sort_id:1" class="edit_employee">User1</div><div id="plan_id:1;sort_id:2" class="edit_employee">User2</div>



Anstellung&nbsp;&nbsp;

Stundenlohn&nbsp;&nbsp;

Festlohn&nbsp;&nbsp;

Bonus&nbsp;&nbsp;

Kassenminus&nbsp;&nbsp;

Nachtzuschlag&nbsp;&nbsp;

Sonstiges&nbsp;&nbsp;

</div>
```

Table-Code is generated with CodeIgniter.

I have no idea why the result looks like that

Some hint?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't mix div's in your th-Tag?

Comment: have you inspected the content of the data variable that is returned by using breakpoint?

Comment: @McPepper I second that - use spans instead of divs, or even just add the classes to the <th> tag instead of wrapping contents

Comment: The data returned by .get seems to be ok. i checked it with alert etc...
the div's in th are needed...

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, You can use `.load()` to get/post data and replace the contents of a selected set: see http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slash at the end of the tag that starts the table. Only some tags can be closed with the slash, and if a tag isn't allowed to have the slash, it will be kept open for the rest of the page, which will make your html invalid. This is what it should look like:

```
<table border='0' cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0' class='mitarbeiter'>
    <thead>
        <!-- ... -->
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- ... -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ahm... ok :) now i just want to bang my head against the next wall :)
thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Table-Code is rendered NOT COMPLETELY LIKE HTML but table renders like normal view. Check is there any config option for Table-Code module to generate FULL HTML table.

Which method do you use to render table?

Comment: the table is rendered with codeigniter $this->table->generate()
i checked the loadurl and the data returned directly in my browser. Table is completely rendered

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed - the table is self closed on the first line:

```
<table border= '0'cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0' class='mitarbeiter' />
```

Should be:

```
<table border= '0'cellpadding='4' cellspacing='0' class='mitarbeiter' >
```

I strongly suspect this is your problem sir.

Comment: ahm... ok :) now i just want to bang my head against the next wall :)
thanks so much